# debugging smtp | ubuntu 12.04, postfix, dovecot

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, vps, dovecot

I cannot sucessfully connect to my smtp server from my mail client.

I am getting the following errors in my `/var/log/mail.log` file

```
Dec 21 15:08:04 pareto postfix/smtpd[11101]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 flush data
Dec 21 15:08:04 pareto postfix/smtpd[11101]: read from B96D2180 [B96C1EB3] (5 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFF))
Dec 21 15:08:04 pareto postfix/smtpd[11101]: read from B96D2180 [B96C1EB3] (5 bytes => 0 (0x0))
Dec 21 15:08:04 pareto postfix/smtpd[11101]: SSL_accept:failed in SSLv3 read client certificate A
Dec 21 15:08:04 pareto postfix/smtpd[11101]: SSL_accept error from unknown[69.165.232.221]: lost connection
Dec 21 15:08:04 pareto postfix/smtpd[11101]: lost connection after STARTTLS from unknown[69.165.232.221]
Dec 21 15:08:04 pareto postfix/smtpd[11101]: disconnect from unknown[69.165.232.221]
```

I did some debugging but can't seem to find the problem

```
root@pareto:/etc/dovecot# telnet localhost smtp
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 pareto.qpapaya.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo localhost
250-pareto.qpapaya.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 30720000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

I used the [linode setup guide](http://library.linode.com/email/postfix/dovecot-mysql-ubuntu-10.04-lucid), and it says that I should expect:

```
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
```

But as you can see that is not showing up.

dovecot.conf:

```
# 2.0.19: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.0.18-linode43 i686 Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ext3
mail_location = maildir:/home/vmail/%d/%n/Maildir
namespace {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  prefix = INBOX.
  separator = .
  type = private
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
postmaster_address = postmaster@qpapaya.com
protocols = "imap pop3"
service auth {

  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix                                                           
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }

  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = vmail
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  mechanisms = plain login
}
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/home/%u/%d/%n allow_all_users=yes
  driver = static
}
protocol lda {
  auth_socket_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Apple's Mail doesn't like self signed SSL certificates.

Tried with thunderbird and it works!